# RSS Feed app doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm working with android studio and when I launch the app it doesn't work and on android studio show this problem:

```
        09-13 23:41:37.579    2228-2380/? A/SdkSpecific17﹕ null
        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.google.android.location.os.real.SdkSpecific17.d(SourceFile:266)
        at ees.run(SourceFile:797)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=2228, uid=10011 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getCurrentUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:3871)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.getCurrentUser(ActivityManager.java:1948)
        ... 5 more
        09-13 23:41:37.719    2228-2380/? A/SdkSpecific17﹕ null
        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.google.android.location.os.real.SdkSpecific17.d(SourceFile:266)
        at efb.D(SourceFile:933)
        at dno.c(SourceFile:126)
        at dno.x_(SourceFile:149)
        at dnk.b(SourceFile:952)
        at dmr.b(SourceFile:331)
        at ees.run(SourceFile:798)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=2228, uid=10011 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getCurrentUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:3871)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.getCurrentUser(ActivityManager.java:1948)
        ... 10 more
```

can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=2228, uid=10011 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
```

You need to add to your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />
```

That being said, I've not seen this permission before... I believe it's used when you require root access. So you also might need a phone that is rooted.

Comment: If it solved it, I'd appreciate if you marked the answer as correct. If you have another question, please post another question.